Ubuntu Server 20.04.6 doesn't doesn't detect Ethernet card
MotherBoard: ROG STRIX X670E-E GAMING WIFI
I can normally install and use Ubuntu Server 24.04, but Ubuntu Server 20.04 cannot access the internet.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS was the 2020-April release; and uses a kernel from that time by default (GA = 5.4); where as Ubuntu 24.04 LTS being a much newer release (2024-April) uses a far newer kernel (GA = 6.8), but other kernel stack(s) are available; did you try the 5.15 kernel (HWE option for 20.04) for example? with default kernel stack being select by your install media used.  Your question as written is actually only a statement, and gives no specifics except release (20.04 being LTS has kernel stack options)
